# How can I access a jQuery variable from AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following code :

```
$('#postTrx').click(function(){
    var hargaBrg = $("tbody").find("tr").eq(i).find("td").eq(3).text();
    var id = $("tbody").find("tr").eq(i).find("td").eq(0).text();
    var jumlah = $("tbody").find("tr").eq(i).find("td").eq(4).text();
    $.ajax({    
        type : "post",
        url : "input_pembelian.php",
        data: "{'idBeliBarang':" + id + ",'harga':'" + hargaBrg + "','jumlah':'" + jumlah + "}",                    
    }); 
});
```

How can I access a jQuery variable from AJAX?

Comment: what is `i`?....

Comment: you already access variable in ajax !!!

Comment: Looks like you're posting invalid JSON. Try `contentType: 'application/json', processData: false, data: JSON.stringify({idBeliBarang: id, harga: hargaBrg, jumlah: jumlah})`

Comment: Possible duplicate. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11687217/variable-data-in-ajax-call-jquery

Comment: thank's David JorPan, I will Try...

Comment: exactly what variables are you trying to capture? are you wanting the results of the ajax call, for that you need to add a success or done function.  I suggest you read the docs: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: i mean , i want to get value from table html, and then i want to post that value to "input_pembelian.php" so that insert to database .

Comment: what is i ? i is iteration for get number row of tr, - @Muthu Kumaran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was try with following code, and response is complete, but no data insert into database, and i was check the query is right :

```
$('#postTrx').click(function(){
var hargaBrg = $("tbody").find("tr").eq(1).find("td").eq(1).text();
var id = $("tbody").find("tr").eq(1).find("td").eq(0).text();
var jumlah = $("tbody").find("tr").eq(1).find("td").eq(2).text();


$.ajax({    
    type : "post",
    url : "input_pembelian.php",
    data: "{'idBeliBarang':" + id + ",'harga':'" + hargaBrg + "','jumlah':'" + jumlah + "}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function () {
        alert("complete");
     },
    error: function (err) {
        alert(err);
    }   
});
```

});